# How to test ngrx router store selector

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-router-store

In our app we have a simple store, containing at root level an `AuthState` and a `RouterState`. The `RouterState` is created through `@ngrx/router-store` methods.

We have some selectors which have to use the RouterState to retrieve for example a param and then combine it for example with other selector result.

Our problem is we cannot manage to find a way to correctly setup test suite to be able to test such combined selectors.

## Reducer setup

### App module imports

```
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),
StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({
  stateKey: 'router',
}),
StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument(),
```

`reducers` beeing the following:

### Reducers

```
export interface RouterStateUrl {
  url: string;
  queryParams: Params;
  params: Params;
}

export interface State {
  router: fromNgrxRouter.RouterReducerState<RouterStateUrl>;
  auth: fromAuth.AuthState;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  router: fromNgrxRouter.routerReducer,
  auth: fromAuth.reducer,
};

export const getRouterState = createFeatureSelector<fromNgrxRouter.RouterReducerState<RouterStateUrl>>('router');

export const getRouterStateUrl = createSelector(
  getRouterState,
  (routerState: fromNgrxRouter.RouterReducerState<RouterStateUrl>) => routerState.state
);

export const isSomeIdParamValid = createSelector(
  getRouterState,
  (routerS) => {
    return routerS.state.params && routerS.state.params.someId;
  }
);
```

Here is AuthState reducer:

```
export interface AuthState {
  loggedIn: boolean;
}

export const initialState: AuthState = {
  loggedIn: false,
};

export function reducer(
  state = initialState,
  action: Action
): AuthState {
  switch (action.type) {
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

export const getAuthState = createFeatureSelector<AuthState>('auth');
export const getIsLoggedIn = createSelector(
  getAuthState,
  (authState: AuthState) => {
    return authState.loggedIn;
  }
);

export const getMixedSelection = createSelector(
  isSomeIdParamValid,
  getIsLoggedIn,
  (paramValid, isLoggedIn) => paramValid && isLoggedIn
)
```

## Test setup

```
@Component({
  template: ``
})
class ListMockComponent {}

describe('Router Selectors', () => {
  let store: Store<State>;
  let router: Router;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{
          path: 'list/:someId',
          component: ListMockComponent
        }]),
        StoreModule.forRoot({
          // How to add auth at that level
          router: combineReducers(reducers)
        }),
        StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({
          stateKey: 'router',
        }),
      ],
      declarations: [ListMockComponent],
    });

    store = TestBed.get(Store);
    router = TestBed.get(Router);
  });
```

### tests and their result

#### Test 1

```
it('should retrieve routerState', () => {
  router.navigateByUrl('/list/123');
  store.select(getRouterState).subscribe(routerState => console.log(routerState));
});
```

> { router:
>          { state: { url: '/list/123', params: {someId: 123}, queryParams: {} },
>            navigationId: 1 },
>         auth:
>          { loggedIn: false } }

as you can see the `getRouterState` selector doesn't retrieve only the `router` slice of the state but an object containing the whole `routerState` + `authState` `State`. router and auth are children of this object. So the selector doesn't manage to retrieve proper slices.

#### Test 2

```
it('should retrieve routerStateUrl', () => {
  router.navigateByUrl('/list/123');
  store.select(getRouterStateUrl).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
});
```

> undefined - TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

#### Test 3

```
it('should retrieve mixed selector results', () => {
  router.navigateByUrl('/list/123');
  store.select(getMixedSelection).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
});
```

> undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'loggedIn' of {auth: {}, router: {}}

### Note

Please note the syntax

```
StoreModule.forRoot({
  // How to add auth at that level
  router: combineReducers(reducers)
}),
```

seems mandatory if we want to combine selectors using multiple reducers. We could just use `forRoot(reducers)` but then we cannot test ONLY router selectors. Other parts of state would be inexistent.

For example, if we need to test:

```
export const getMixedSelection = createSelector(
  isSomeIdParamValid,
  getIsLoggedIn,
  (paramValid, isLoggedIn) => paramValid && isLoggedIn
)
```

we need both router and auth. And we cannot find a proper test setup which allows us to test such a combined selector using `AuthState` and `RouterState`.

## The problem

How to setup this test so we can basically test our selectors?

When we run the app, it works perfectly. So the problem is only with testing setup.

We thought maybe it was a wrong idea to setup a testBed using real router. But we struggle to mock the routerSelector (only) and give it a mocked router state slice for testing purpose only.

It's really hard to mock these router selectors only. Spying on `store.select` is easy but spying on the `store.select(routerSelectorMethod)`, with method as argument becomes a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you can mock selector dependencies with `projector` property:

**my-reducer.ts**

```
export interface State {
  evenNums: number[];
  oddNums: number[];
}

export const selectSumEvenNums = createSelector(
  (state: State) => state.evenNums,
  (evenNums) => evenNums.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr)
);
export const selectSumOddNums = createSelector(
  (state: State) => state.oddNums,
  (oddNums) => oddNums.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr)
);
export const selectTotal = createSelector(
  selectSumEvenNums,
  selectSumOddNums,
  (evenSum, oddSum) => evenSum + oddSum
);
```

**my-reducer.spec.ts**

```
import * as fromMyReducers from './my-reducers';

describe('My Selectors', () => {

  it('should calc selectTotal', () => {
    expect(fromMyReducers.selectTotal.projector(2, 3)).toBe(5);
  });

});
```

Taken from [official docs](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/testing.md#testing-selectors)

Answer (score 4):

struggling with this one myself, the 'state' property of the routerState was undefined. I found the solution which worked for me was calling the router.initialNavigation() to kickstart the RouterTestingModule which in turn sets up the router store.

In my case I needed to test a CanActivate guard which utilizes both root store selectors and feature store selectors. The testing module setup below works for me:

```
describe('My guard', () => {

   let myGuard: MyGuard;
   let router: Router;
   let store: Store<State>;

   beforeEach(async(() => {
       TestBed.configureTestingModule({
           imports: [
               RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
                   {
                       path: '',
                       redirectTo: 'one',
                       pathMatch: 'full'
                   },
                   {
                       path: 'one',
                       component: MockTestComponent
                   },
                   {
                       path: 'two',
                       component: MockTestComponent
                   }
               ]),
               StoreModule.forRoot({
                   ...fromRoot.reducers,
                   'myFeature': combineReducers(fromFeature.reducers)
               }),
               StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({
                   stateKey: 'router', // name of reducer key
               }),
           ],
           declarations: [MockTestComponent],
           providers: [MyGuard, {provide: RouterStateSerializer, useClass: CustomSerializer}]
       }).compileComponents();

       myGuard = TestBed.get(MyGuard);
       router = TestBed.get(Router);
       store = TestBed.get(Store);
       spyOn(store, 'dispatch').and.callThrough();
       router.initialNavigation();
   }));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. `router.initialNavigation()` didn't work for me. What worked for me was `await router.navigate(['']); done();` in  a `beforeEach(async(done) => {});`

Answer (score 0):

I know its not direct solution, but in my opinion very nice workaround which enables testability:

you can define mock state:

```
provideMockStore({
      initialState: {
        router: {
          state: {
            root: {
              params: { param1: value1 },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }),
```

This way routeter selectors will return the corresponding so you can provide mock data.

I've written a medium article of this issue
https://medium.com/@su.ede.kovacs/mock-ngrx-router-store-selector-eecaf4d6d845